# Geonode to harvest metadata from Geonetwork-like services?

Tags: geoserver, metadata, geonetwork, geonode

I am in charge of setting up a gis web portal and one of the functionalities would be to harvest some metadata from metadata servers like Geonetwork. I have been thinking of using Geonode because I have already used Geoserver. Apparently Geonode uses Pycsw to publish metadata but I can't see whether it allows to collect metadata from other servers and how? Is it possible to do it through the Geonode interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can harvest directly with pycsw:

http://geopython.github.io/pycsw-workshop/docs/intro/intro-exercises.html#metadata-harvesting

I am not sure if GeoNode has [some UI to configure this](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/issues/770), you should probably ask on geonode's mailing list directly. Although, depending on what is required, probably installing directly a geonetwork will be better for your needs.

Comment: In fact, it is possible to configure Geonetwork as geonode´s CSWbackend instead of pycsw. Here´s how: http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/csw_settings/